# Firebase Realtime Database Overrides my Data at a location even when I use .push() method

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Realtime Database Overrides my Data at a location even when I use .push() method. The little-concrete knowledge I have about writing to Firebase Realtime database is that writing to Firebase real time database can be done in few several ways. Two of the most prominent are the

1. set() and 2. push() method.

The long story short, push() is used to create a new key for a data to be written and it adds data to the node.

So fine, firebase has being co-operating with me in my previous projects but in this, I have no idea what is going on. I have tried different blends of push and set to achieve my goal but no progress so far.

In the code below, what I want to achieve is 2 things, write to a location chatUID, message and time only once, but write severally '-MqBBXPzUup7czdG2xCI' all under the same node "firebaseGeneratedId1" ->

A better structure is below.

[image: Sample Database location]
Help with code. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is my code
The writers reference

```
_listeningMsgRef = _msgDatabase
.reference()
    .child('users')
    .child(userId)
    .child('chats')
    .child(chatUIDConcat);
```

When a user hits sendMessage, here is the function called

```
void sendMessage() {
    _messageController.clear();
    var timeSent = DateTime.now().toString();

    //Send
    Map msgMap = {
        'message': msg,
        'sender': userId,
        'time': timeSent,
        'chatUID': chatUIDConcat
    };

    //String _key = _listeningMsgRef.push().key;

    _listeningMsgRef.child(chatUIDConcat).set().whenComplete(() {
        SnackBar snackBar = const SnackBar(content: Text('Message sent'));
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        DatabaseReference push = _listeningMsgRef.child(chatUIDConcat).push().set(msgMap);
    });
}
```

The idea about the sendMessage function, is to write

```
chatUID:"L8pacdUOOohuTlifrNYC3JALQgh2+q5D38xPXVBTwmwb5Hq..."
message: "I'm coming"
newMessage: "true"
sender: "L8pacdUOOohuTlifrNYC3JALQgh2"
```

When it is complete, then push new nodes under the user nodes.

**EDIT**:

I later figured out the issue. I wasn't able to achieve my goal because I was a bit tensed while doing that project. The issue was I was wanted to write new data into the '-MqBBXPzUup7czdG2xCI' node without overwriting the old data in it.

The solution is straight forward. I just needed to ensure I wrote data in that node as new nodes under it. Nothing much, thanks
Frank van Puffelen for your assistance.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that isn't working as you expect/want it to. That'll make it much more likely someone can help explain what the code does, and how to make it do what you want.

Comment: I apologise for the late response. Stackoverflow gave me pain trying to format my code.

Answer (score 0):

Paths in Firebase Realtime Database are automatically created when you write any data under then, and deleted when you remove the last data under them.

So you don't need to first create the node for the chat room. Instead, it gets auto-created when you write the first message into it with `_listeningMsgRef.child(chatUIDConcat).push().set(msgMap)`